# In R DT datatable, how to create complex header table

Tags: r

How to transfer 'left datatable' to 'right datatable'(I want to transfer variables 'factory' and 'color' to the header (complex header)
)

```
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)

factory <- c("F1", "F1", "F1", "F1", "F1", "F1", "F1", "F1", "F1", "F1", "F1", "F1", "F1", "F1", "F2", "F2", "F2", "F2", "F2", "F2", "F2")
color <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C")
category <- c("cat1", "cat1", "cat1", "cat2", "cat2", "cat2", "cat2", "cat2", "cat2", "cat2", "cat3", "cat3", "cat3", "cat3", "cat3", "cat3", "cat3", "cat4", "cat4", "cat4", "cat4")
amount <- c(279, 185, 43, 249, 17, 63, 243, 71, 286, 41, 271, 285, 138, 109, 123, 258, 174, 114, 177, 30, 32)
my_data <- data.frame(factory,color,category,amount)
my_data$ID <- seq_len(nrow(my_data))
my_data <- my_data %>% select('ID',everything())

datatable(my_data)
```

[image]

Comment: You need this for display purpose ? So `tidyr::pivot_wider(my_data, names_from = c(color, factory), values_from = amount)` would not work?

Comment: Thanks,  i want to display it in HTML file (currently i use DT::datatable() to create HTML file, is there way to show 'pivot_wider' result in DT::datatable ? )

Comment: Yes, If you save the output of `pivot_wider` in `df1` you can do `DT::datatable(df1)`.

Comment: thanks, maybe this is as prilminary way for mypurpose